# this binding in Angular vs React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, this

I am just Starting React ,i got the concept why should we bind **this** in React but How Angular is Taking care of this i am Confused

## React

```
class Product extends React.Component {
  a= "mdb"
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // this.handleUpVote = this.handleUpVote.bind(this)
  }

  // Inside `Product`
  handleUpVote() {
    console.log("we are looking at This",this.a) //undefinded
    this.props.onVote(this.props.id);
  }}
```

## Angular

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  ngOnInit(){
    this.checkName()
  }
checkName() {
  console.log(this.name) // OP- angular 
}
}
```

How **this** worked in Angular Without `.bind(this) or Arrow Function` of Es7  What did i miss ?

Comment: What do you mean by "how"? It is working as it should in any typescript code. It is not connected to react or angular in any way.

Comment: Thanks for Comment @Dimanoid
i want to know the Difference , i don't see any difference betwen TypeScript in JavaScript with binding of  this so i want to know i one case(Angular) why it is working and why not in another case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about angular or react. It's just the behavior of **this** in javascript that you have to bind it explicitly or use arrow functions which uses lexical **this binding** which automatically binds them to the scope they are defined in. And TypeScript is pretty good at finding the “nearest object” or knowing the lexical scope, so TypeScript can give you exact information on what to expect from this. [here](https://fettblog.eu/this-in-javascript-and-typescript/) it's explained good or [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/) to understand **this' behavior** in javascript and react.